# Javascript and Wordpress: JS not loaded

Tags: javascript

I am working on [this](http://weierweg-liestal.ch/wohnen/) **Wordpress** [website](http://weierweg-liestal.ch/wohnen/) and i am a using a bit of JS to animate the table.

What i need is to "**filter**" the Table rows when a checkbox on top is selected. For example when Zimmer -> 4.5 is selected, only the `rows` with class `.zimmer4` are displayed. I am using now this script but does not works:

JS:

```
$(document.body).on('change', "#zimmer5", function() { 
    $("#tableID tr.zimmer5").toggle(!this.checked); 
});    

$(document.body).on('change', "#zimmer4", function() { 
    $("#tableID tr.zimmer4").toggle(!this.checked); 
});

$(document.body).on('change', "#zimmer3", function() { 
    $("#tableID tr.zimmer3").toggle(!this.checked); 
});

$(document.body).on('change', "#zimmer2", function() { 
    $("#tableID tr.zimmer2").toggle(!this.checked); 
});
```

This is the HTML code i am using for the buttons

**HTML**

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Zimmer
        <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<form class="filter">
<input id="zimmer4" class="unchecked" type="checkbox">4.5
<br>
<input id="zimmer3" class="unchecked" type="checkbox">3.5
<br>
<input id="zimmer2" class="unchecked" type="checkbox">2.5
<br>
</form>
</ul>
</span>
```

Comment: How did you integrate this script into your website? Are the functions already available? Do you get any errors? Is this inside an onready block?

Comment: thats jquery you are using, not vanilla javascript, have you loaded jquery?

Comment: I am using a plugin in. https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/css-javascript-toolbox/

i used the exactly the same plugin in on another website and it works: http://birsmatt.ch/wohnungen/

Comment: Fix what? You stated your objective but haven't explained what the problem is. *"does not work"* is not a proper problem statement. Please include relevant html in the question

Comment: I see the following JS error: "*Error: TypeError: $ is not a function 
Source File: http://weierweg-liestal.ch/wohnen/ 
Line: 1640*" That should put you down the right path.

Comment: @charlietfl what i need is to filter the rows using JS. Basically show/hide rows on checkbox "checked".

Comment: Well for starters need to use console and chase errors as already pointed out. Once that is done code shown might even work as it is

Answer (score 1):

replace your $ sign with jQuery

Comment: So easy. THANK YOU!